# How can Recognize handwriting number

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

Which algorithms should use to recognize handwriting numbers from an image?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on where you're trying to implement/the resources available to you.

I've used [Support Vector Machine learning](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_digits_classification.html) for that task; you have to feed in individual characters to train your algo.

take a look at python's scikit-learn and if you ned to implement on FPGA check out: [MyHDL](http://www.myhdl.org/)

Comment: - Restricted Boltzmann Machine learning -> http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_rbm_logistic_classification.html
 - K-Means clustering ->
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_digits.html
 - Manifold learning ->http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/manifold/plot_lle_digits.html

Comment: (Sorry I have low rep on this exchange and cannot post more than 2 links)